# Conflict between Yoast and Woocommerce (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, yoast

Thank you for your time reading this. Hopefully you can help me out!
I have a WordPress website (Linstar theme) and I noticed a conflict between Woocommerce and Yoast SEO.

When Yoast is activated, and I try to edit a page which displays products, I get a blank page with a black dot after updating. The changes did come through though. This only happens after updating pages which have products in it.

I used the debug mode for WordPress and the error led me to this piece of code.

```
if($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() && is_array($woocommerce->cart->get_cart())) {
    foreach($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart) {
        $items_in_cart[] = $cart['product_id'];
    }
}
```

When I deactivate this piece of code, no problem occurs after updating pages which include products.

I searched the internet, but couldn't find anyone else with the same problem. Could you help me out? Thanks in advance!

Kind regards, 
Daisy

Comment: It seems something that can be solved updating both plugins. I know it was 7 months ago but I am interested if you found a solution to it.

Comment: Hi there. I didn't find a solution for it which is too bad. Thank you for your idea! Currently I'm using a different theme so I don't have the problem anymore :)